# my compare statement not working in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I was doing an exam algorithm earlier (Just started vb 5 days ago so be nice ;) ) and I realised after testing that for whatever reason my statement `If 0 < CInt(Num(x)) < 10` was not working which completely baffled me as I would thinkk that of all things THIS would be the easiest but no. No matter what I did, it just would always be true even if I made Num(X) = 90 or 9000000 it wouldn't matter, so if anyone knows what obvious mistake I have made whether its because I made it a string or what let me know :)

```
 Dim Num(2), INPUT As String
        Dim Cond As Boolean = False
        Dim Valid As Boolean = False
        Dim Isnum As Boolean
        Dim x, Number, IsTen As Integer

        While Cond = False
            Do Until IsTen = 3 And Number = 3
                IsTen = 0
                Number = 0
                For x = 0 To 2
                    MsgBox("Please enter a number")
                    Num(x) = (Console.ReadLine)
                    Isnum = IsNumeric(Num(x))
                    If Isnum = True Then
                        IsTen = IsTen + 1
                    End If
                    If Isnum = True Then
                        If 0 < CInt(Num(x)) < 10 Then
                            Number = Number + 1
                        End If
                    End If

                Next
                If Number <> 3 Then
                    MsgBox("Sorry all three numbers werent between 0 and 10, Please enter again")
                End If
                If IsTen <> 3 Then
                    MsgBox("Sorry all three inputs werent numbers, Please enter again")
                End If
            Loop
            MsgBox("All three numbers are valid")
        End While
```

Comment: FYI few (if any) computer languages support a three-way comparison like you appear to be trying to do.  Comparisons are usually two-way, so you must combine them (with "and" or "or" operations, typically `AndAlso` or `OrElse` in VB) to obtain a range.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would advise is setting Option Strict On at the top of your code file.  You can also make this the default via Visual Studio options.  This will warn you about the implicit type conversion that is causing your problem.

Changing the line

```
If 0 < CInt(Num(x)) < 10 Then
```

I'm assuming the intent here is to ensure the number is greater than 1 but less than 10

To something like this:

```
If Isnum = True Then
    Dim val As Integer = Integer.Parse(Num(x))
    If (val > 0) AndAlso (val < 10) Then
        Number = Number + 1
    End If
End If
```

Notice the use of Integer.Parse() to type cast the string to Int, it's a little more robust but there is also the Integer.TryParse() which is another step up again, might be worth reading up on.  Also notice AndAlso usage, this is a short circuit operator so if the First condition is false, doesn't bother evaluating the next.